# Polymorphism with List and arrayList

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I've got the next

```
public interface MyInterface{}
public class ClassA implements MyInterface(){}
public class ClassB extends ClassA{}
```

In theory, the valid references types for an object B are the following:

```
MyInterface myIn = new ClassB();
ClassA o1 = new ClassB();
ClassB o2 = new ClassB(); 
Object o3 = new ClassB();
```

If I try to do something like this ...
`List<MyInterface> o1 = new ArrayList<ClassB>();`

I get a compilance error.
Any idea?

Comment: `Generics` are working at compile time, so the `generic` `<ClassB>` in `ArrayList<ClassB>()` is quite unecessary. The `generic` you´ll see as more importent is `List<MyInterface>`, as this defines the `generic` `List` at compile time. As a sidenode, that´s also why jdk 1.7 introduced the empty `diamond operator` when intializing a `List` for example, the right hand `generic` simple can be left out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList<ClassB>` can contain only instances of `ClassB` or sub-classes of `ClassB`.

On the other hand, a `List<MyInterface>` can also contain instances of `ClassA` (which are not necessarily instances of `ClassB`) and any other instances that implement `MyInterface`.

Therefore you can't assign an `ArrayList<ClassB>` to a `List<MyInterface>` variable.

If you want the  `o1` list to contain any `MyInterface` instances, you should assign to it an `ArrayList<MyInterface>`.

If you want `o1` to contain only instances of `ClassB`, change its type to `List<ClassB>`.

Comment: But in theory all objects of class ClassB are objects of ClassA and therefore of implemented interface too. Indeed if I try to do this                 Myinterface o1 = new ClassB(); it compiles ok

Comment: @silviaDominguez But not all objects of ClassA have to be objects of ClassB.

Comment: @silviaDominguez `ClassB` implements `MyInterface`, so you can make that assignment. However, `ArrayList<ClassB>` does not implement `List<MyInterface>` - it implements `List<ClassB>`. And `List<ClassB>` is not a sub-interface of `List<MyInterface>` and cannot be assigned to a variable of this type.

Comment: @EranThus although ArrayList implements List, here I can´t use polymorphism right?